# Multiple internal networks on Virtual box (CentOS)

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I have 3 NIC's (internal network) on one Virtual box Machine(CentOS 6.4) each NIC has its own network name intnet1,intnet2 and intnet3. So how I understand this is eth0 is connected to internal network 1, eth1 is connected to internal network 2 and so on. When I start up another VM(CentOS 6.4) with only one NIC connected to intnet1 I can ping all 3 NIC's on the 'server' VM but if I now change the clients internal network to intnet2 the VM cannot find the 'server' VM. Have I misunderstood how the internal network of virtual box works? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was needed was to give each network adapter its own unique netmask as it seems that when one tries to ping it tries the first adapter and if that fails does not try the other adapters since they are on the same subnet. -Credit to my friend for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

while configuring internal network in VirtualBox you have to make sure the below things are properly configured.

- Network name has to be same as the other machine.It must have same
  network name(setting--> network -->network name)
- In network adaptor settings - default gateway has to be same for both
  the machines.(you can verify it from ipconfig)

> Turn off the windows firewall.(In order to make sure that connection
>   is not internally blocked)

Please check whether the above are properly configured and try pinging the other server and check

Comment: Firewalls are turned off and I dont see how gateways are an issue since as I understand the internal network its a virtual direct link. Just to be clear I'm on a windows PC using to CentOs virtual machines. Can windows affect this virtual connection in anyway because as I understand the Vbox website the internal network does not even use your PC's real network adapter?

Comment: Setting each NIC to have its own netmask seemed to have fixed the problem